# Simple webserver or web testing framework

Tags: python, web-services, testing, web-applications

Need to testcase a complex webapp which does some interacting with a remote 3rd party cgi  based webservices. 
Iam planing to implement some of the 3rd party services in a dummy webserver, so that i have full controll about the testcases.
Looking for a simple python http webserver or framework to emulate the 3rd party interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org), take a look at Hello World:

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Run this code and you have a very fast Hello World server ready on `localhost` port `8080`!! Pretty easy huh?

Answer (score 2):

You might be happiest with a WSGI service, since it's most like CGI.

Look at [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look the standard module wsgiref:

https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/wsgiref.html

At the end of that page is a small example. Something like this could already be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: +1: I agree that included wsgiref server is probably enough for his needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler sense to mock (or stub, or whatever the term is) urllib, or whatever module you are using to communicate with the remote web-service?

Even simply overriding `urllib.urlopen` might be enough:

```
import urllib
from StringIO import StringIO

class mock_response(StringIO):
    def info(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("mocked urllib response has no info method")
    def getinfo():
        raise NotImplementedError("mocked urllib response has no getinfo method")

def urlopen(url):
    if url == "http://example.com/api/something":
        resp = mock_response("<xml></xml>")
        return resp
    else:
        urllib.urlopen(url)


is_unittest = True

if is_unittest:
    urllib.urlopen = urlopen

print urllib.urlopen("http://example.com/api/something").read()
```

I used something very similar [here](http://github.com/dbr/themoviedb/blob/cc6fbb3c67df9bcedc14e2bcdfc1e56c06da0c33/stub_urllib.py), to emulate a simple API, before I got an API key.