# python vs java on web service development?

Tags: java, python

i am currently using php as backend language in webdevelopment. but im wondering what you need to install to get running with python and java.

with php i need apache and mysql.

can i use those for java and python too?

i cant find good guides equivalent to LAMP/MAMP/WAMP so i understand the parts when using either java or python. would be great if you could give me some good links on the installation and what is required.

and i have read that its easier with python. but is this the only advantage of using python instead of java. cause with java i can create java applets, desktop and mobile applications. they all tend to have java installed. but not python.

so why should i use python instead of java.

Comment: "i cant find good guides equivalent to LAMP/MAMP/WAMP"?  What does this mean?  You couldn't find http://onlamp.com/?  What are you trying to do?  What have you read so far?  Your question is (a) vague and (b) a duplicate of dozens on SO.  Please clarify it or read the other questions already here and ask something more specific

Comment: Exact Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309662/comparing-the-uses-applications-of-java-vs-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only give suggestions for web development in python:

- Use [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) - A non blocking web server.
- Use [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/) - A templating engine.
- Use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) - A schema less database server | You can also use any RDBMS according to your requirement.

Above 3 tools are enough to build a web application in python.

or you can always choose [Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/) - The giant web framework with all the features required to build a scalable web application in python.

Comment: Tornado 0.2 was released September 2009. Nothing after that. I'm a bit disappointed.

Answer (score 4):

You need to look into the `Web Application Framework` subject. Some SO pointers:

- [simple-webserver-or-web-testing-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776495/simple-webserver-or-web-testing-framework)
- [web-application-frameworks-c-vs-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289941/web-application-frameworks-c-vs-python)
- [django-vs-other-python-web-frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702179/django-vs-other-python-web-frameworks)
- [what-web-application-framework-for-java-is-recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596/what-web-application-framework-for-java-is-recommended)
- [can-anyone-recommend-a-simple-java-web-app-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116978/can-anyone-recommend-a-simple-java-web-app-framework)
- ...

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

[web2py](http://www.web2py.com/) is a python web framework that is completely self-contained, runs portably off a USB drive even. The manual is available on [scribd](http://www.web2py.com/examples/default/docs), and after an hour or two of tutorial you will have a pretty good idea of what a python web framework will be like. I can't comment on Java at all.

EDIT: Django and web2py are very, very similar.  I think I prefer web2py because it *does more* for me that I don't have to do, but from the POV of, say, Java frameworks, Django and web2py may as well be the same thing.